# Return NULL if calculated value falls within a range

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am performing a rather simple calculation on a date field, and I'd like to return NULL values in cases where the date precedes predefined date. In essence, I'm looking for the most effective way to perform a `NULLIF` using an operator other than equality.

The below is an example of what I'd like to do (obviously the syntax fails):

```
SELECT
    Id,
    NULLIF(DATEADD(DAY, -180, SurveyDate),  
        {LESS THAN} '20190101')
FROM dbo.Vendor
```

I get the desired result using the following query, but it seems a bit clunky and verbose:

```
SELECT
    Id,
    CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, -180, SurveyDate) < '20190101'
        THEN NULL
    ELSE
        DATEADD(DAY, -180, SurveyDate)
    END
FROM dbo.Vendor
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simplification that you can do is drop the `ELSE` part of the `CASE` statement:

```
CASE WHEN DATEADD(DAY, -180, SurveyDate) >= '20190101' THEN DATEADD(DAY, -180, SurveyDate) END
```

I can't see how you can have only 1 call to the function `DATEADD()` without introducing more complexity to the code.

Comment: Thanks for adding your input. I felt like I would be stuck making two calls to `DATEADD()`, but I wasn't sure if there was a `NULLIF()` type function that worked non-equality operators.

Answer (score 1):

You can put an inline IIF statement.  Makes it a bit less 'clunky'

```
SELECT Id, IIF(DATEADD(DAY, -180, SurveyDate) < '20190101', NULL, DATEADD(DAY, -180, SurveyDate)) AS SurveyDate
FROM dbo.Vendor
```

Comment: `IIF` was introduced in 2012, it will not work for older versions.

Answer (score 0):

First, it's high time to upgrade the database server.
Please note that 2008 and 2008 r2 versions extended support ended on 9 July 2019 - which means no more updates, not even security patches will be developed (Of course, Microsoft reserves the right to publish security patches even after extended support ends).
For more information, read [The End of SQL Server 2008 and 2008 R2 Extended Support](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/database-administration/the-end-of-sql-server-2008-and-2008-r2-extended-support/) on RedGate.

Having said that, with 2008 r2 you don't have too many choices - A case expression is probably your only viable option.
however if you don't want to write the `dateadd` twice you could use `cross apply` like this:

```
SELECT
Id,
CASE WHEN TargetDate < '20190101'
    THEN NULL
ELSE
   TargetDate
END
FROM dbo.Vendor
CROSS APPLY
(
    SELECT DATEADD(DAY, -180, SurveyDate) As TargetDate
) As td
```

This might seem a bit like an overkill in this simple case, but when you have a complex expression or multiple computed columns that's when `cross apply` comes in very handy.